# Rails 7 jquery: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I added jQuery to my Rails 7.0.2.4 project by the following:

First run command `./bin/importmap pin jquery`, to add the following line in `config/importmap.rb`:

```
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
```

Then add lines to import jQuery in `app/javascript/application.js`:

```
import '@hotwired/turbo-rails'
import 'controllers'
import 'bootstrap'

import jquery from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = jquery
window.$ = jquery
```

My view with javascript:

```
<%= form_with(model: @micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class='field'>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Compose new micropost...' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <span class='image'>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </span>
<% end %>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('#micropost_image').bind('change', function() {
    if (this.files[0].size/1024/1024 > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB.  Please choose a smaller file.')
      $('#micropost_image').val('')
    }
  })
</script>
```

When the view is loaded, Chrome console shows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at (index):103:3
```

And when I select a file bigger than 5MB, no error message is popped up, so I think the script isn't run.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $("#micropost_image").bind("change", function() {
    const size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert("Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.")
      $("#micropost_image").val("");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.